# Dynamically switch databases and create their views from deltalake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am a newbie to Synapse. I need your help with a task I've been working on for a few days. I want to create views in SA for my delta tables from Deltalake. I have the below folder structure in my gold container.

**Gold:**

1. P3138

   - Frames *(delta folder)*
   - Columns *(delta folder)*
   - Walls *(delta folder)*
2. P3139

   - Frames *(delta folder)*
   - Columns *(delta folder)*
   - Walls *(delta folder)*
   - Beams *(delta folder)*

In the above structure P3138, and P3139 are the Projects(id) in the Gold container, and the Frames, columns, and so on are delta tables with some data. Using the ADF pipeline I can create a database with the project_id if it does not already exist in the synapse serverless SQL.

**"Now, the task is to create views for each delta table from the Delta Lake into its respective database in Synapse (which has already been created). I am unable to dynamically switch between databases and create views within them."**

I attempted to use stored procedures and script activities coupled with For-Each and GetMetadata activities to achieve this. However, I encountered difficulties in creating views. The image below depicts the inner pipeline responsible for creating views, and I intend to pass the project IDs as parameters from the outer pipeline

Synapse pipeline:

[image: Inner pipeline which creates the views, projectId is passes from outer pipeline forloop]

I want something like this:

```
USE @projectID
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC CreatesQLserverlessView_gold @ViewName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @statement VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @statement = N'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ' + @ViewName + ' AS
    SELECT *
    FROM
        OPENROWSET (
        BULK ''https://kkdadventureworks.dfs.core.windows.net/gold/'+@projectID+'/'+ @ViewName + '/'',
        FORMAT = ''DELTA''
        )as [result]
    '
EXEC (@statement)

END
GO
```

Comment: P3138  is foldername? and Frames, columns, are subfolders?

Comment: yes. P3138 is a folder with subfolders (frames, columns..) which are delta tables or call them folders of delta tables.

Comment: using serverless sql pool or dedicated sql pool

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it.**

After creating the database, I simultaneously create a stored procedure with the following code. The key aspect here is that I made the linked service itself dynamic for databases:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC CreatesQLserverlessView_gold 
@DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),
@ViewName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Switch the database context
SET @statement = N'USE ' + @DatabaseName + ';'
EXEC (@statement)

-- Create or alter the view
SET @statement = N'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ' + @ViewName + N' AS
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK ''https://keveebimdata.dfs.core.windows.net/gold/' + @DatabaseName + N'/' + @ViewName + '/'',
    FORMAT = ''DELTA''
) AS [result]'

EXEC (@statement)
END
```

Then, in my Synapse environment, I trigger the stored procedure for each table. Since each database already has the stored procedure within it, I simply need to switch the database at the linked service level. Subsequently, the stored procedure creates views for each delta table within their respective databases.

[image: Pipeline]

[image: SP inside the forloop]